# ¿Cómo quedarme con registros únicos en SQL?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la tabla CTA y hago un LEFT JOIN con la tabla domicilios para obtener el ESTADO. En esta última tabla las cuentas suelen tener asociados más de un domicilio, necesito quedarme con un único resultado, el más actual registrado para evitar que se dupliquen o tripliquen los registros.
Las tablas contienen los siguientes campos:

[image: Esta es mi tabla CTA]

[image: Esta es mi tabla Domicilios]

[image: Este es el resultado que busco, solo el registro más actual]

```
---Mi código erróneo 
SELECT 
a.Cuenta, a.segmento, a.Saldo, b.Estado, b.Fecha_actualización 
FROM dbEStatus.dbo.Cta a
left join dbEStatus.dbo.Domicilios b
```

Answer (score 2):

Dependiendo de la versión de SQL Server (2008 o superior), la forma, tal vez más simple y óptima podría ser:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT a.Cuenta, 
       a.segmento, 
       a.Saldo, 
       b.Estado, 
       b.Fecha_actualización, 
       row_number() over (partition by a.Cuenta order by b.Fecha_actualización desc) as Rn
       FROM dbEStatus.dbo.Cta a 
       left join dbEStatus.dbo.Domicilios b
            on a.cuenta = b.cuenta
)
SELECT *
       FROM CTE
       WHERE Rn = 1;
```

---

Básicamente generamos un numerador (`Rn`) por `cuenta` y ordenado por `Fecha_actualización` descendente, esta consulta la usamos como subconsulta mediante una [common table expresion,](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) para filtrar las primeras filas de cada grupo que corresponden al último domicilio de cada cuenta

Comment: Justo iba a poner un código similar. Pero tuve que editar la respuesta porque el punto y coma debe terminar las instrucciones, no iniciarlas.

Comment: Gracias @LuisCazares, es cierto, es una cuestión idiomática personal, en general no suelo escribir el ; final en las sentencias, por lo que cuando uso CTE la costumbre es ponerlo al principio, para evitar el error de sintaxis.